# Using Promise.all but only want the value of 2 of the resolved promises?

Tags: javascript

I understand that I can do this to make things cleaner:

```
const [result2, result3] = await Promise.all([p2, p3]);
```

but i have the following code where I only care about the values of 2 of the promises.  Is there I way I can adapt this following code to be cleaner like the above?

```
// array of other Promises
this.allAwaitingPromises = [p1, p4];

await Promise.all(this.allAwaitingPromises);
const result2 = await p2();
const result3 = await p3();
```

Comment: What is `allAwaitingPromises`?

Comment: a class variable that is an array of other promises

Comment: Please include that code in your question - its definition is essential

Comment: apologies, updated to indicate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the two values you want first in the array of promises, then list the others later. You can then use `Promise.all` on the whole array, but destructure to only use the first two values from it.

```
const [result2, result3] = await Promise.all([p2, p3, p1, p4]);
```

or, if p2 and p3 are functions that return promises, but p1 and p4 are just promises -

```
const [result2, result3] = await Promise.all([p2(), p3(), p1, p4]);
```